# Pydev interactive IPython consoles freezes on Pandas dataframe completition?

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pandas, ipython, pydev

I'm using large dataframe from Pandas in the interactive IPython console in Pydev/Eclipse. Every time I try to access dataframe attributes or methods, the console freeze for a few seconds after I type `df.`. Apparently it looks for completitions and maybe accidently calls some lengthy operation in the background.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: add versions of pydev, pandas, python and eclipse and anything that could be relevant for debugging this behaviour

Comment: Pydev 3.4.1; Pandas 0.13.1; Python 3.3.3; Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_code_analysis.html

Comment: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_features.html

Comment: what have you already tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can control much of the behaviour by setting Eclipse Preferences. You can start to disable all and try re-enable things you need.

- PyDev->Editor->Code Analysis
- PyDev->Editor->Code Completion

What could be your problem

- [Request completion on '.'](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_complctx.html)

Other Strategies

- Disable Code Analysis within special modules by using a special
  comments in source.
- Disable Automatic Code Analysis and trigger it with a shortcut (show all pydev shortcut with SHIFT+CTRL+L)

Comment: I checked the options and - as expected - the "Request completition" is the problem. However, just turning it off isn't really a solution. Completition helps to suggest the names of the pandas dataframe variables. This completition is somehow generated dynamically and apparently the interactive console enters some code it shouldn't do. I'm not familiar with how IPython checks for completition or how Pandas injects the column names dynamically.

Comment: Try "Apply completion on." or try to play with "AutoCompletion delay".

Comment: It's not really Pydev's fault. You get the same behaviour if you write a class with a custom `__getattribute__` which . Delaying the freeze won't help much. Whenever it gets to completition, Pydev/Pandas executes some code it shouldn't.

Comment: PyDev can accept a 'note' to warn it not to make code-analysis at all in some module. In order to do that' move cursor to the first line of the module and press 'Ctrl+1' and choose the @PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore flag. Doing that will add a note in the code to warn that this module should not be analyzed by PyDev.

Comment: Sure. But this is not about Code analysis. I open the interactive console. I load my pandas dataframe (called `df`). I type `df.` and it freezes for a couple of seconds. There isn't really a place to add comments.

Comment: Please add a sample pydev IPython console session to your question.